# Showing parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter while calling a procedure using java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure using java.

I am a beginner in stored procedure.
So tried the same first in mysql terminal

```
mysql> delimiter // 
mysql> create procedure get_EmployeeName(IN cust_id INT,OUT cust_name varchar(20)) 
    -> begin 
    -> select name into cust_name from CUSTOMERS where id = cust_id; 
    -> end // 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec) 

mysql> delimiter ; 
mysql> call get_EmployeeName(1,@cust_name); 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec) 
mysql> select @cust_name; 
+------------+ 
| @cust_name | 
+------------+ 
| A          | 
+------------+ 
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I am able to get the output.

Now tried using Java.

Create procedure statement

```
stmt.execute("create procedure mydb.WhoAreThey(IN id INT, OUT name VARCHAR(20)) begin select Name into name from employees where EmployeeID = id; end");
```

Procedure Call

Not sure if my procedure call is right or wrong

```
        String IN = "1000";
        cs = con.prepareCall("{call WhoAreThey(?,?)}");
        cs.setString(1, IN);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.execute();
```

Above call gives an sqlexception
**"SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter"**

**UPDATE**

worked by calling "  cs = con.prepareCall("{call mydb.WhoAreThey(?,?)}");"

But When I did **select @name**..it is showing "Null".

I expected my out as "David Walker" from employees table as EmployeeID is 1000.

```
mysql> select * from employees;
+------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
| EmployeeID | Name         | Office | CreateTime          |
+------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
|       1000 | David Walker | HQ101  | 2016-12-21 13:00:37 |
|       1001 | Paul Martin  | HQ101  | 2016-12-21 13:00:37 |
+------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I checking in a wrong way(select @name)

Comment: Are you sure the stored proc was created?

Comment: @shmosel: Yes it is created. checked using show procedure status. There I can see "WhoAreThey" as 1 entry

Comment: Your first parameter is integer and you are setting string into it. Is that a problem?

Comment: @PVR: Changed string to int. But still showing the same error (int IN = 1;
            cs = con.prepareCall("{call WhoAreThey(?,?)}");
            cs.setInt(1, IN);
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);)

Comment: Try calling procudure by mydb.WhoAreThey.

Comment: Or use procedure get_EmployeeName which is already created in database so that you can cross verify.

Comment: @PVR:It worked by calling mydb.WhoAreThey. But my output is null.tried directly in db also it is also returning null.why is it so ?please see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131127/discussion-between-pvr-and-unmesha-sreeveni).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling **WhoAreThey** call **mydb.WhoAreThey**

```
 String IN = "1000";
    cs = con.prepareCall("{call mydb.WhoAreThey(?,?)}");
    cs.setString(1, IN);
    cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.execute();
```

To fetch the value of OUT param USE:

```
String name = cs.getString(2);
```

Comment: outputting a null value.whether my procedure is right?

Comment: The same procedure with different name that is get_EmployeeName is working fine right?

Comment: Yes that is working correctly. I changed table from CUSTOMERS to employees for java program